# Why does this code work fine as middleware and not as a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

This code works fine if it is launched in this matter:

```
app.route('/upload').post(rulesUpload.upload(obj),function (request, response, next) {
    response.status(200).end('File Caricato/i Con Successo');
});
```

and not if I write:

```js
app.route('/upload').post(function(request, response, next) {
  rulesUpload.upload(obj);
  response.status(200).end('File Caricato/i Con Successo');
});


var  formidable  =  require('formidable'),
      util  =  require('util'),
      fs    =  require('fs-extra');
var defaultMaxSize = 3;
var defaultMaxFiles = 1;

exports.upload = function(obj) {
  return function(req, res, cb) {
    var check = '';
    var errors = {};
    for (key in req.files) {
      if ((obj.required != undefined && req.files[key].size == 0) && (obj.required[key] != undefined && obj.required[key]))
        check = "Il file " + key + " è obbligatorio!";
      else if (obj.destination[key] == undefined)
        check = 'Il file ' + key + ' non è gestito correttamente.';
      else if (obj.files[key] != undefined && obj.files[key] < req.files[key].length)
        check = 'Non si possono inserire più di ' + obj.files[key] + ' file per il campo ' + key;
      else if (obj.files[key] == undefined && defaultMaxFiles < req.files[key].length)
        check = 'Non si possono inserire più di ' + defaultMaxFiles + ' file per il campo ' + key;
      else {                
        var  new_location  =  obj.destination[key] + '/';
        var numFiles = 1;
        if (req.files[key].length != undefined)
          numFiles = req.files[key].length;
        if (numFiles == 1)
          req.files[key] = {
            0: req.files[key]
          };

                    
        for (var  i  =  0;  i  < numFiles;  i++)  {                
          var  file_name  = '';
          if (obj.filename[key] != undefined) {
            file_name = obj.filename[key].name;
            if (file_name == undefined)
              file_name = req.files[key][i].name.substring(0, req.files[key][i].name.lastIndexOf("."));
            if (obj.filename[key].prefix != undefined)
              file_name = obj.filename[key].prefix + file_name;
            if (obj.filename[key].suffix != undefined)
              file_name += obj.filename[key].suffix;
            file_name += req.files[key][i].name.substring(req.files[key][i].name.lastIndexOf('.'), req.files[key][i].name.length);
          } else file_name = req.files[key][i].name;
          if (obj.fileTypes[key] != undefined) {
            var re = new RegExp(obj.fileTypes[key]);
            var mimetype = re.test(req.files[key][i].type);
            var extname = re.test(req.files[key][i].name.toLowerCase());
            if (!mimetype && !extname)
              check = "Sono Accettate solo le seguenti estensioni: " + obj.fileTypes[key] + " per il campo " + key;
          }
          if (obj.fileSize[key] != undefined && req.files[key][i].size > obj.fileSize[key] * 1024 * 1024)
            check = 'I file ' + key + ' non possono superare i ' + obj.fileSize[key] + " MB";
          if (obj.fileSize[key] == undefined && req.files[key][i].size > defaultMaxSize * 1024 * 1024)
            check = 'I file ' + key + ' non possono superare di default i ' + defaultMaxSize + " MB";
          if (check == '') {                
            var  temp_path  =  req.files[key][i].path;

                            
            fs.move(temp_path,  new_location  +  file_name,  function (err)  {                    
              if  (err)  {                    } 
              else  {                    }                
            });
          } else {
            errors[key] = check;
          }
          if (check != "")
            errors[key] = check;

        }
        if (check != "")
          errors[key] = check;
      }
      if (check != "")
        errors[key] = check;
      check = '';            
    }
    if (check != "")
      errors[key] = check;
    check = '';
    if (errors != {})
      return cb(util.inspect(errors));
    else return cb(null);        
  };
  return;
};
```

P.S.: For the superusers, I know that there is a bug in return phase but I didn't find any solution and it is a secondary problem.

P.S.2: For the curious, I use this code for check iif the files sent can be upload or not.

Comment: Your method returns a function, so it'd be `rulesUpload.upload(obj)(request, response, next);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to write asynchronous code with nodejs.. middleware takes the request, response, and the callback, and after finishing it gives it to the next middleware...

Read what the upload function is returning, its returning a function, which is a middleware..

```
app.route('/upload').post(middleware1, middleware2, ..., callback)
```

so if you want to handle the upload in your callback directly, you have to call it, and then pass another function to it.

```
app.route('/upload').post(function (request, response, next) {
    rulesUpload.upload(obj)(request, response, function(err) {
         if (!err) {
           return response.status(200).end('File Caricato/i Con Successo');
         } else {
           // do something with the err..
         }
    });
});
```

So this codes get more complicated.. so use middleware )

Comment: I know that it more complicated but, some times, it doesn't work because I must pass a variable from a function to another! However thank you!

Comment: However your code returns that response is undefined! Why?

Comment: not sure what you mean, you should use the middleware approach anyway. the code above is not tested, just to give you an idea of the asynchron style of nodejs and middleware

Comment: Well, I must insert a row into my db and then pass a variable (the id) to the upload function ... If I understand well if I did something like .post(createNewUser(),upload()) node.js try to execute these method in the same time so it doesn't work for me ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you call upload as a synchrone function, but it's async due to fs.move. In addition your call return a function.
Just pass a callback to your function and call it like this :

```
rulesUpload.upload(obj, function(){
 response.status(200).end('File Caricato/i Con Successo');
})
```

And change the prototype to :

```
exports.upload = function(obj, cb) {
 // return function(req, res, cb) { // REMOVE THIS LINE
```

Comment: There is a problem ... the app returns firstly that doesn't find req, than, after that I added req between the parameters into the module, returns that cb is non a function

Comment: i haven't seen that you use req, so replace prototype by exports.upload = function(req, res, obj, cb) and call it with exports.upload(req, res, obj, function(){

But what is job ?? it seems to be never defined

Comment: I used this module also to manage the creation of a new user soit should call after the creation of the row into the database ...